# Invisible comments in jsf 2.0?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, comments, facelets, invisible

is it possible to embed comments in my .xhtml-files that are only displayed in the source and not the rendered result?
I want to include author, date,... in the files but they should not be visible to the enduser in the generated output. If I use the standard comment-tags  `<!-- -->` the browser displays them.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Add the following into your `web.xml`:

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

This way `Facelets` will skip the comments while parsing the view `xhtml` template.

Comment: No changes. My jboss 5.1 still try to run the content between the comments.

Answer (score 19):

Invisible comments in JSF is a drawback, specially for beginers. I agree with answer of Mr Minchev. Anyway, I provide an alternative way to comment content in JSF consisting of using **ui:remove**

```
<ui:remove> This is a comment </ui:remove>
```

The UI Remove tag is used to specify tags or blocks of content that should be removed from your page by the Facelets view handler at compile time. This tag has no attributes. You can use this tag to indicate that a particular tag should be removed from the rendered page.

It's useful to remove content which is required during [design time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17320914/practical-implications-of-facelets-uiremove-tag), but not during run time, such as comments, some stubbed content (e.g. "lorem ipsum") which aids in filling up the page content to fit the layout in visual designers such as Dreamweaver, etc.

See: [Practical implications of Facelets ui:remove tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17320914/practical-implications-of-facelets-uiremove-tag)

Note that the Facelets ***compilation process is much faster than the JSP compilation process*** because no Java bytecode is actually generated and compiled behind the scenes when you first visit your page. The UI Remove tag is used to specify tags or blocks of content that should be removed from your page by the Facelets view handler at compile time. This tag has no attributes.

> [Examples of both comment options](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/how-to-use-comments-in-jsf-2-0/)

Answer (score -6):

Wrong, the right way is:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>  
    <param-value>true</param-value>
```

This work for me, javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS no!

Comment: Question was about JSF 2.x, not 1.x. JSF 2.0 was introduced 5 years ago already. Perhaps it's time to catch up?