# why jsf2 does not parse comments by default

Tags: jsf-2

i've been pondering about this for a while. If one of the first things one learns in any language is how to use comments, why on earth did designers of jsf2 decide that it would be nicer to have xhtml comments disabled by default? what purpose does it serve?

thanks

Comment: What does _'have xhtml comments disabled'_ mean? And what is _'not parsing comments'_? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500738/invisible-comments-in-jsf-2-0 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388109/how-can-i-remove-html-comments-in-my-facelets... It does parse them by default..

Comment: @Kukeltje http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/how-to-use-comments-in-jsf-2-0/ Note that i am not askig how to enable comments. I am asking why you have to enable them instead of that being the default behavior.

Comment: It **does** parse comments by default as you can read in my links, my comment AND the mkyong one posted by you.